# Where put /resources/ in Spring MVC ? Using application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC to create my WebSite.

But I dont understand how/where put my resources if I want to used application.properties instead of xml configuration.

I have enable @EnableAutoConfiguration tag in my project.

I have this [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XDlr.png).

I'm using JSP like this:

```
<img src="/images/logo-ack.png" style="width: 60%;">
```

How I can access to this resources setting the path on application.properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Spring initializr** for this, because it will starts a project with structure offered by Spring. The website is https://start.spring.io/